# Qt: Session management error: Authentication Rejected. None of the authentication protocols specified are supported and host-based authentication fail

Tags: linux, xorg, freebsd, fonts

I know that it is not supported and experimental,but I tried to install maya 2022 (trial) in freebsd 13.1-RELEASE,inside the linuxulator. Unfortunately an error prevents maya from running:

```
/usr/sbin/chroot /compat/ubuntu /bin/bash

root@john-connor# /usr/Autodesk/maya/bin# ./maya
        
    Qt: Session management error: Authentication Rejected, reason : None of the authentication protocols specified are supported and host-based authentication failed
        
root@john-connor# /usr/Autodesk/maya/bin# xset +fp /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi
        
    xset:  bad font path element (#0), possible causes are:
    Directory does not exist or has wrong permissions
    Directory missing fonts.dir
    Incorrect font server address or syntax
        
root@john-connor# /usr/share/fonts/X11# printenv | grep ^SESSION_MANAGER
    SESSION_MANAGER=local/john-connor:/tmp/.ICE-unix/9345
```

Suggestions ?

Comment: Are you running this under Linux chroot?

Comment: the linux emulator under freebsd is like chroot,yes.

Comment: No, did you literally `chroot` into Linux install directory and running stuff from there?

Comment: yes,I run the linux executables by invoking first :  /usr/sbin/chroot /compat/ubuntu /bin/bash

Comment: The `/tmp/.ICE-unix/9345` is most likely invalid under chroot. Not sure what to do about that, though.